# Mostrar dados de uma função ajax, em outra função ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma função ajax que procura o código de todas as empresas e vai na outra função ajax procurar os funcionários.

Para que a página não trave ao fazer essa procura estou utilizando o atributo `async: true`, só que ao fazer isso, não consigo o retorno dos dados na página mesmo funcionando usando o `console.log()`

Segue meu código para ser analisado

```js
$( document ).ready( function(){
   empresas()
   
  } )
  
  let empresasArr = {
 "empresa":[
  {
    "nome": "Digiboard", 
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "nome": "HAM", 
    "id": 2
  }
  ]
  }
  
  let dadosArr = {
   
   "dados": [
      {"nome": "Carlos", "empresa": 1},
      {"nome": "Vicente", "empresa": 2},
      {"nome": "Maiza", "empresa": 2},
      {"nome": "Charles", "empresa": 1},
      {"nome": "Michel", "empresa": 2}
       ]
  }
  function empresas(){
    $.ajax({
   url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/b0c22',
   type: 'post',
   dataType: 'json',
   async: false,
 }).done( function( d ){
    var retorno = "";
    let string = ""
    console.log( d )
     
    $.each( d.empresa, function(i, j){
        console.log( j.nome )
     
     retorno = fnNomes( j.id, function( retorno ){
    //console.log( retorno )
    string =+ retorno
     }  )
     
    
    })
    console.log( string )
    $('.retorno').append(string)
 })
  }
  
  function fnNomes( id, cb ){

 let nomes = "";
    
 $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1cksbu',
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { empresa : id }
  }).done( function( d ){
       
    console.log( d )
    $.each( d.dados, function(i, j ){
     if( j.empresa == id ){
      
           nomes += j.nome+"<br>"
     }
    })
   
    cb( nomes )
              
  } )
 // console.log(nomes);
  return nomes
  }
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
  
  <div class="retorno"></div>
```

o arquivo ***Empresa.json***

```
{
 "empresa":[
    {
      "nome": "Digiboard", 
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "nome": "HAM", 
      "id": 2
    }
 ]
}
```

O aqruivo ***dados.json***

```
"dados": [
   {"nome": "Carlos", "empresa": 1},
   {"nome": "Vicente", "empresa": 2},
   {"nome": "Maiza", "empresa": 2},
   {"nome": "Charles", "empresa": 1},
   {"nome": "Michel", "empresa": 2}
  ]
```

Ouvi falar num tal de deferred e promised, não se resolveria o problema, mas ainda não entendi como usálos

Answer (score 0):

Da forma que você está fazendo não seria necessário fazer o primeiro Ajax síncrono, até porque isso não é uma boa prática. O Ajax deve ser assíncrono, como o próprio nome sugere: ***A***synchronous **Ja**vaScript e **X**ML.

O erro está na forma em que você está requisitando as páginas usando `type: 'post'`. O `type: 'post'` seria no caso de você enviar informações via `data:`, o que não é o caso. O que você deseja é receber um JSON (`dataType: 'json'`).

Solução:

- remova as linhas `type: 'post',`
- remova `async: false,` e `async: true,` (o `true` não é necessário porque o Ajax já é `async`)

Desta forma o segundo Ajax será chamado normalmente quando o primeiro for concluído (`.done()`).

Comment: No segundo eu gostaria de enviar o post